# Why can't I validate my Azaure AD JWT signature?

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt

I have an application registered on my Azure AD tenant. When I receive the access token after logging in I send the token to my node.js API. I'm trying to validate the signature but I keep getting "invalid signature" error. The JWT header lists the specific key that it supposedly used to sign the token. So why can't I verify it? Is there something I need to tweak in the AAD configuration? Are there options I need to specify that I pass to `azure-ad-jwt`? I've tried passing in `{ audience: 'https://graph.windows.net'}`. I've also tried passing in the audience that is in the decoded token as well as the specific `kid` that is listed in the header so that it only tries the specific key that the token says it is signed with.

This is my code that is giving me the error:

```
const aad = require('azure-ad-jwt');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const jwtToken = req.headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');

    aad.verify(jwtToken, null, function (err, result) {
        if (result) {
            console.log("JWT is valid");
            next();
        } else {
            console.log("JWT is invalid: " + err);
            res.status(401).json({
                message: "Auth failed"
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: How did you get the token? And what the resource did you get the token for?Could you decode the token in https://jwt.io/ and show the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

If your front-end is acquiring a token for audience `https://graph.windows.net`, then that token is not meant for your API.
It is a token for Azure AD Graph API.
You should not be validating that.

Instead, your front-end needs to specify your API app's client id or app ID URI as the resource (if using the v1 endpoint/ADAL) or valid scopes defined by your API (if using the v2 endpoint/MSAL).
Then you will get a token you can validate.

Comment: So this is interesting. I'm actually using Postman to acquire a token to send to my API to test with. I configured an API permission in Azure. When I specify the scope tied to that permission (and only that scope) then validation works. However, if I specify anything else in addition to that scope (i.e. openid, profile) then it fails. Even the base-64 encoded token looks very different. Another observation is that when I use my custom scope by it self, the access token comes back with a `"scp": "email openid profile User.Read"` claim in the decoded body. This leads to many more questions.

Comment: When acquiring a token, you should only specify scopes for one API.